# Modifying the HTML generated for Menus

Tags: 7, routes

I've read the questions already asked but they didn't answer my question. But they were sucessful in confusing me more. There are hooks, render functions of two types, theme functions, pre-processing functions, processing functions. In every question I read over internet the answer is different every time. My head's gonna explode.

Coming to question, I need just the `text` & `href` from menu-item or link. I'll handle the rest.

**How I want it?**

```
//I need control over the HTML wrapper elements for menu
foreach $menu_items as $menu_item:
    if(has_submenu($menu_item)):
        print "custom html here";
        foreach $menu_item as $sub_menu_item:
            print "custom html here".$sub_menu_item['name'].$sub_menu_item['href']."custome html here";
    endif
    print "custom html here".$menu_item['name'].$menu_item['href']."custome html here";
```

Comment: No! No! No! enough with marking duplicates. Newbies like me get lost moving from one question to another. The situation changes, question changes & because its asked by someone else, what one knows also changes. Most of the time gets spent on reading others questions only to find out that its not I want or to find its too complicated to understand. Its just too inefficient. I asked a direct question. I need a direct answer please

Comment: We can certainly point you to the right functions/disciplines within Drupal, but I just want to make sure you know that we can't write your full code for you. What I mean is that if an answer to a different question provides the theoretical answer to your question, it will be closed as a duplicate - we don't provide one-one support, so if it's a matter of 'that one works but I want it blue', then it's fair game to be closed as a dupe. I'm not saying this _is_ a dupe (though I suspect it is, this has been asked quite a few times if I recall), just don't be shocked if it does get closed as such

Comment: A bit more info from you would actually be useful in working that out - how is this menu being rendered? Through theme_links in a template file or some other method?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use: [menu_tree_all_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7). It will get a menu tree of your given menu machine name.